# Only show data for today and in the future

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating a website that lists upcoming events, events are saved in a DB.

I am trying to only show events that are happening today or in the future, not in the past

here is my code:

```
("SELECT * FROM events where deleted='0'  AND date > CURDATE() ORDER by STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC ")
```

However this doesn't seem to show anything at all, can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Try ´date >= CURDATE()´

Comment: Hi, No that didn't work?

Comment: are you storing the date as timestamp?

Comment: I have managed to do it, ` $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events where deleted='0' and STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') >= CURDATE() ORDER by STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC ")or die('No Audit Selected' );
      `

Comment: To avoid date conversion to string, I would use ´SELECT * FROM events where deleted='0' and date >= DATE(NOW()) ORDER by STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC´

Answer (score 0):

The field `date` seems to be in the `'%d/%m/%Y'` format and is not defined as `date`, `datetime`, or `timestamp` data type.

**Change**:

```
SELECT * FROM events 
where  deleted='0' 
  AND  date > CURDATE() 
ORDER by STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC
```

**To**:

```
SELECT * FROM events 
where  deleted='0' 
  AND  STR_TO_DATE( date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) >= CURDATE() 
ORDER by 
       STR_TO_DATE( date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) ASC
```